# files in .hg directory show up when I run "hg status"

Tags: mercurial

I am working on a project in Mercurial, and all of a sudden, when I run "hg status", I see a bunch of files in my ".hg" directory, reported as "not tracked". It looks like this:

```
? .hg/00changelog.i
? .hg/00manifest.i
? .hg/branch
? .hg/branchheads.cache
? .hg/data/.hgignore.i
? .hg/data/.htaccess.i
? .hg/data/autostart.cgi.i
? .hg/data/common.py.i
? .hg/data/common.pyc.i
? .hg/data/cron.i
? .hg/data/index.html.i
```

The list is much longer. I can show you everything if you want. Why is this happening? I know that files in ".hg" are special to Mercurial but why is it suddenly telling me now? It is annoying to have my status listing cluttered with this stuff. How can I make it stop?

Comment: The .hg directory contains the whole local repository, so it's very very strange that `hg status` tells you that your repository is untracked. :-) How have you created your repository? `hg init`, `hg clone` or anything else?

Comment: I can't remember exactly what I did. Maybe I accidentally deleted some files in .hg, or maybe it was cosmic rays. From now on, I will pay close attention to what I am doing and if it happens again, I will post some more details here.

Comment: What version of Mercurial are you running?  Does `hg root` give the answer you'd expect?

Comment: Try running `hg verify` to ensure the the repo isn't corrupt.

Comment: I created it with `hg clone`. I am using Mercurial 1.7.5. `hg root` gives me the directory of my repo, like I would expect.

Comment: When I run `hg verify`, I see lines like `warning: orphan revlog 'data/jinja2cache/__jinja2_7e0bd821d058541195fc5a44d447095127064a86.cache.i'`. I can show you the whole output if you want. I am deliberately not versioning my jinja2cache files.

Comment: I can't make it happen in local experiments, but maybe you accidentally added a file in your .hg directory?

Comment: as a workaround you can use .hgignore (add .hg to list of ignored files)

Answer (score 1):

Try cloning your repository and see if the problem persists in the new clone.  If it doesn't you can copy over any uncommitted files to it and then adjust the default pull path in .hg/hgrc and forget about the broken clone.  You may want to save the broken clone until you are sure everything you need is safely in the new clone.